# Binding Reset In Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to do a simple collection in backbone.js, but I don't understand why my callback function (specified in bind) isn't being called.  From what I understand from the documentation, when I do a fetch(), the reset event should be triggered. Any suggestions? (Code is below).

```
            Customer = Backbone.Model.extend(
            );
             CustomerList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model : Customer,
                url : "test.php",
            });

            var ChartView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $('body'),


                initialize: function(){
                    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                    this.collection.bind("reset", self.render);
                    this.collection.fetch( 
                    );

                },

                render : function() {
                    console.log("render");
                }

            });

            var chartView = new ChartView( { collection: new CustomerList()} );
        })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using backbone 1.0.0 you should be passing `reset:true` to reset. Else it will just `set` the models to the collection which was the erstwhile `update`

```
this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
```

Ensure the response from the url is a valid json. `reset` event will be fired only on success.

Comment: Looks like I was using an outdated tutorial and copied the link to backbone 0.3.3. When I switched to 1.0.0, everything work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check this out. like @nikoshr said on  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16538588/1211174. there is sync event. so instead forcing backbone to reset the collection each time  you can catch the sync

https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator/issues/164

```
    this.collection.bind("sync", function(){
                         console.log('got sync');
                         this.render(){, this  );
```